# What is the most performant way to color code geom_sf polygons based on a value in the dataset?

Tags: r

Im using ggplot, and trying to plot a facetted national map where zones are colored based on a value in the dataset. My approach is taking >24h to render. Is there a better way?

```
basemap <- ggplot2::map_data("world") %>%
    dplyr::filter(region == "my country of interest")

zones <- sf::st_read("my_zones.shp") # contains a ZONE_NAME column

mydata <- readr::read_csv("my_data.csv",
    col_types = list(
        ZONE_NAME   = readr::col_factor(), # consistent with ZONE_NAME above
        category    = readr::col_factor(), # the value to facet by
        status      = readr::col_factor(), # the value to color code by (high, med, low)
    )
)
```

My current approach is to merge zones and data

```
zones <- zones %>% dplyr::full_join(mydata, by = "ZONE_NAME")
```

Then build the plot

```
ggplot2::ggplot() +
    # plot the basemap
    ggplot2::geom_polygon(data = basemap, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),
      fill = "gray85", color = "gray80") +
    # plot the color coded zones
    ggplot2::geom_sf(data = zones, aes(fill = status) +
    # facet by category
    ggplot2::facet_wrap(vars(category))
```

The zones shapefile is somewhat large/complex, but not crazily so. If I plot the zones alone (without merging mydata), the ggplot object takes at most half a minute to render.

When I attempt to produce the facetted plot after merging mydata, it takes more than 24hours on recent Macbook Pro.

Is there a better way to approach this problem?

Comment: How many levels do you have? What's the return value of `levels(mydata$status) |> length()`? If `status` is numeric it can be very big.

Comment: 3 levels - high, med and low

Comment: Are the final row count of `zones` and counts of `zones$ZONE_NAME` s  (i.e. `table(zones$ZONE_NAME)` ) as expected? Is there a specific reason for using a full join instead of left/right/inner join?